# PHP imagecopyresampled giving resource error only for gif images

Tags: php, image, gd

When i pass a black image background generated by `imagecreatetruecolor` to `imagecopyresampled`, its giving an error as parameter 1 in `imagecopyresampled` is expected to be resource but an integer given.

This is happening for `gif` images only. Also, i am using `imagecolortransparent` for gifs so that the animated ones do not appear as static with a black background but it also when is passed to `imagecopyresampled` gives the same error.

without `imagecolortransparent`:

```
function resizeImageGIF($image,$width,$height,$scale) {
    $newImageWidth = ceil($width * $scale);
    $newImageHeight = ceil($height * $scale);
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);
    $source = imagecreatefromgif($image);
    imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,0,0,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$width,$height);
    imagegif($newImage,$image);
    chmod($image, 0777);
    return $image;
}
```

The above generates a static gif with black background and gives the same PHP error of integer given in parameter 1

With `imagecolortransparent`:

```
function resizeImageGIF($image,$width,$height,$scale) {
    $newImageWidth = ceil($width * $scale);
    $newImageHeight = ceil($height * $scale);
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);
    $black=imagecolorallocate($newImage,0,0,0);
    $newImageTransparent = imagecolortransparent($newImage,$black);
    $source = imagecreatefromgif($image);
    imagecopyresampled($newImageTransparent,$source,0,0,0,0,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$width,$height);
    imagegif($newImageTransparent,$image);
    chmod($image, 0777);
    return $image;
}
```

this one generates an animated gif but still with the above error and also **do not** scale the images as a result image pops out of the fixed width container.

Answer (score 1):

try this script and this script working for me

```
$size = 200; // the thumbnail height
$filedir = 'uploads/'; // the directory for the original image
$thumbdir = 'uploads/'; // the directory for the thumbnail image
$prefix = 'small0_'; // the prefix to be added to the original name
$maxfile = '2000000';
$mode = '0666';
$rnd_1 = rand(11111,99999); 

$userfile_name= $rnd_1.'_'.$_FILES['image']["name"];
$userfile_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$userfile_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$userfile_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) 
{
$prod_img = $filedir.$userfile_name;
$prod_img_thumb = $thumbdir.$prefix.$userfile_name;
move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $prod_img);
chmod ($prod_img, octdec($mode));
$sizes = getimagesize($prod_img);
$aspect_ratio = $sizes[1]/$sizes[0]; 
if ($sizes[1] <= $size)
{

$new_width = '500';
$new_height = '500';
}else{

$new_width = '500';
$new_height = '500';
}
$destimg=ImageCreateTrueColor($new_width,$new_height)
or die('Problem In Creating image');

$srcimg=ImageCreateFromJPEG($prod_img)
or $srcimg=ImageCreateFromPNG($prod_img)
or $srcimg=ImageCreateFromGIF($prod_img)
or die('Problem In opening Source Image0');
if(function_exists('imagecopyresampled'))
{
imagecopyresampled($destimg,$srcimg,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,ImageSX($srcimg),ImageSY($srcimg))
or die('Problem In resizing');
}else{
Imagecopyresized($destimg,$srcimg,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,ImageSX($srcimg),ImageSY($srcimg))
or die('Problem In resizing');
}
ImageJPEG($destimg,$prod_img_thumb,90)
or die('Problem In saving');
}
imagesavealpha($prod_img_thumb, true);
//setting completely transparent color
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($prod_img_thumb, 0, 0, 0, 127);
//filling created image with transparent color
imagefill($prod_img_thumb, 0, 0, $transparent);
imagepng($prod_img_thumb);
}
```

Comment: your code is using the same logic as mine, i don't see how it will not give me the same error.

Comment: it is very strange how `imagecopyresampled` returns an integer for gif images only in my case

Comment: coder101 you just try this script and i'm sure this one will solve your problem

Comment: can you give me your script in pastebin.com let me check it